# Cannot access Rails variable inside Javascript tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

All the other solutions in stackoverflow doesn't seem to work for me so i'm posting my code for assistance. I want to output the variable: @less_per_unit via jquery

Here is my  tag inside _form.html.erb:

```
<script>
$(document).on('keyup', ".input-quantity", function(){ 
  $.ajax({
      url:  "/so_check_increment",
      type: "GET",
      data: { quantity: $(this).val(), product_id: $(this).closest('tr').find('.input-product_code').val()}
  }); 
    $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('.increment').text('<%== j @less_per_unit%>');
}); 
</script>
```

And here is my controller:

```
  def check_increment
    @less_per_unit = "testing"
  end
```

I know that the ajax works, i've also set up the routes. If I try binding.pry, I know that rails can find @less_per_unit, but I can't output it with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because:

Let us say this form is rendered in action 'new' of controller 'Post', then `@less_per_unit` needs to be initialised there to use it in the view file of that action which you are using. Where as you are using an AJAX call and during that call, you are defining an instance variable which will definitely be not accessible to the already rendered html file.

So, you need to return JSON data from your check_increment action and receive that data in AJAX call response and then use it.

Comment: Actually j is rails code for “escape javascript”. I learned that from the other stack overflow questions similar to mine. I tried removing the extra = and j but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Okay. I didn't know that. But why an extra '='. As per documentation, `<%= j @less_per_unit %>` should work fine.

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't show any value. I tried console.log('<%= j @less_per_unit %>') also. No luck.

Comment: So, it logged empty string or nothing? Try to place some random string before <%= statement in console.log whether code flow is even teaching to that statement or not.

Comment: Nothing. It doesn't even produce a null value. I tried displaying a dummy string `@random`. It still just displays blank, but if I do something like console.log("hello") or console.log("<%= "hello" %>", both work.

Comment: Is your form a partial file?

Comment: Yes it is! I also noticed that if I call something unrrelated to my Ajax action, it outputs. ex.) `console.log('<%= current_user.id %>')`. I think that javascript loads the console.log before rails even creates the @less_per_unit object inside the controller. Would you know how I can make sure it is triggered when ajax call is finished?

Comment: You should never use instance variables inside a partial file. Instead pass locals to the partial file while rendering it.

Comment: Though it should not be the cause of problem as instance variables are also accessible inside Partials, but it is a bad practice.

Comment: Try logging `console.log(" abc <%= @less_per_unit%>")` and check what it prints. If it prints "abc", then essentially your instance variable is null.

Comment: Yes, it is null, I think it is because the action is called before the ajax successfully retrieves @less_per_unit, do you have any suggestions on how I can make sure ajax retrieval is finished completely first before my console.log is called?

Comment: Isn't it obvious that this will not work?
The reason is: Let us say this form is rendered in action 'new' of controller 'xyz', then `@less_per_unit` needs to be initialised there to use it in the view file of that action which you are using. 

Where as you are using an AJAX call and during that call, you are defining an instance variable which will definitely be not accessible to the already rendered html file.

Comment: I have some debugging progress. Turns out, I shouldn't be placing the console.log function underneath the same DOM function as ajax. I placed it under a separate file `check_increment.js.erb` and values are outputting now, the problem is now in making sure the text change happens only on affected row.

Comment: So, have you basically understood why your code was not working earlier? I hope you have read the explanation.

Comment: Yes, it's a sequence of events issue. I understand now, I have to create and call the function which pulls `@less_per_unit` only when ajax call is complete. Thanks a lot.